# Reverse a reverse IP

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

How can I take this input:

> 71.3.162.181.in-addr.arpa

and turn it in to this:

> 181.162.3.71

I'm hoping sed and awk can do this, but just don't know where to start?

Comment: The dupe is this in reverse, so you just need to drop the `.in-addr-arpa` with most of them.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk -F. '{ print $4, $3, $2, $1 }' OFS='.' input
```

with `-F.` we define input file **F**ield's separator is dot `.`; then printing fields $4, $3, $2, $1 with dot separated fields set in `OFS='.' (`**O**utput **F**ield **S**eperator)

Answer (score 0):

`sed` alternative:

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+).*/\4.\3.\2.\1/' input
```